# Liquibase loadUpdateData csv rerun

Tags: sql, liquibase

I am running liquibase with the loadUpdateData changeset. I added runOnChange = true and the issue I am having now is a duplicate key. I was  under the impression that loadUpdateData will do an insert and will also do a check if duplicate then update?

currently my liquibase file with the changeset looks like this.

```
    <changeSet id="123" author="ranbir">
    <loadUpdateData tableName="address" primaryKey="address_id" schemaName="public" file="address.csv">
        <column name="address_id" type="NUMERIC"/>
        <column name="street" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="city" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="state" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="zip" type="NUMERIC"/>
    </loadUpdateData>
</changeSet>
```

Table definition

```
<changeSet author="ranbir" id="122">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not><tableExists tableName="address"/></not>
    </preConditions>
    <comment>Create Table</comment>
    <createTable tableName="address" remarks="Table contains addresses">
        <column name="address_id" type="BIGSERIAL" remarks="Uniquely identifies rows in the table">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_address" />
        </column>
        <column name="street" type="VARCHAR(250)">
        </column>
        <column name="city" type="VARCHAR(250)"/>
        <column name="state" type="VARCHAR(250)"/>
        <column name="zip" type="INTEGER"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: It should work, could you please post: 1) several first lines from file 2) table definition 3) full error message

Comment: On the stacktrace it shows failed sql and it says INSERT INTO but there is no "if duplicate update..."

Comment: Yes, that's why we need more details to understand why it works incorrectly.

Comment: I added the table definition above - the file itself is basically the first column is listed as address_id with the id's listed down,  in the B column it is the next column "street" and all the values for those listed down

Comment: @RanbirSingh Have you seen this bug https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2418

Comment: thank you - so seems like liquibase 3.4 has issues with this - is the fix to just upgrade to 3.5?

Comment: @RanbirSingh yes, try to upgrade to 3.4.1 or higher and execute script

Comment: Thank you! upgrading to 3.4.1 worked!